# Can I use IoC container without having interfaces?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, inversion-of-control, ninject, ioc-container

I have an application consisted of maybe more than 80 Web-Api controllers.Each one has the following Constructor definition:

```
public class AlertsController : ApiController
{         
     IAlertsService _alertsService;
     public AlertsController(IAlertsService alertsService)
     {
         _alertsService = alertsService;
     }
}
```

So each time I have to define a new interface just for using the IoC and nothing more. the problem is that I don't find so usefull having lots of interfaces just to avoid coupling layers. Is there a solution to keep using IoC , but without being necesary defining so many interfaces , in my case ?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Yes, if you change the constructor to take an AlertsService class instance (insted of the interface), Ninject will still build up the dependencies of AlertService. However this means your controller is directly coupled to the AlertService class which makes mocking very difficult and will hamper your unit testing. Interfaces are preferable.

Comment: You might be missing the point about DI and loose coupling. [Here's a good introduction](https://livebook.manning.com/#!/book/dependency-injection-in-dot-net-second-edition/chapter-1) to this subject.

Comment: Providing you have separate bindings for IAlertService then you could still bind AlertsController to itself via `Kernel.Bind<AlertsController>().To<AlertsController>()` and it should still resolve its dependencies with the consumer still invoking ninject to get the controller. Apologies if i have misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 0):

The OP doesn't specify what `IAlertsService` *does*, but following the [Dependency Inversion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle), clients should define the API they have a need for, and then it's up to concrete classes to implement the required API.

For the sake of argument, then, let's assume that `IAlertsService` looks like this:

```
public interface IAlertsService
{
    void Foo(Bar bar);
    Baz Qux();
}
```

Without defining any interfaces, you can instead inject two delegates, like this:

```
public class AlertsController : ApiController
{         
     private readonly Action<Bar> foo;
     private readonly Func<Baz> qux;

     public AlertsController(Action<Bar> foo, Func<Baz> qux)
     {
         this.foo = foo;
         this.qux = qux;
     }
}
```

If a class only need the `foo` functionality, there's no need to also inject `qux`, and vice versa.

Since the base class library already defines generic `Action` and `Func` delegates, you don't have to declare any new types for your dependencies.

Once you get used to this style of programming, you may realise that you're just doing [ad-hoc, impure, 'functional' programming](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2017/01/30/partial-application-is-dependency-injection), in which case it's better to program in F# instead.